# Can I get Mockito to return an Optional<String> when a method is callled?

Tags: java, mockito, option-type

I'm probably missing something simple, but no matter what I've tried I cannot get Mockito to return an Optional for a particular method call.

I have the following code:

```
final boolean supportChanged = generateLetterDomainService.isSupportChanged(decisionDomain.findPreviousDecisionEventId(),decisionEvent, customer, year);
```

`decisionDomain.findPreviousDecisionEventId()` returns an `Optional<String>` which is then processed in the `isSupportChanged()` method.

My problem is, no matter what I do, when I exmaine the parameter passed into the method (`previousDecisionEventId`) it's always `Optional.absent()`.

I'm mocking the method call like so:

```
@Mock
 LetterDecisionDomain decisionDomain;
```

And in the test itself:

```
when(decisionDomain.findPreviousDecisionEventId())
    .thenReturn(Optional.of("eventId"));
```

But it doesn't work.
the method `generateLetterDomainService.isSupportChanged()` looks like this:

```
private boolean isSupportChanged(final Optional<String> previousDecisionEventId,
            final DecisionEvent decisionEvent, final Customer customer, final Year year) {
boolean ownershipChanged = false;
if(previousDecisionEvent.isPresent()){
...
}

return ownershipChanged;
}
```

I've tried mocking the Optional object itself, but that doesn't work either, the result is always `Optional.absent()`.

The method concerned:

```
public Optional<String> findPreviousDecisionEventId() {
    if (previousDecisionEvent == null) {
        return Optional.absent();
    }
     return fromNullable(previousDecisionEvent.getId());
}
```

Comment: I think when I have encountered this in the past I just let the mock return the  raw type. Later, when I go to use it, I  simply wrap it with `Optional.ofNullable()`.

Comment: Do you mean `Optional.empty()` or are you referring to an non-Java 8 implementation?

Comment: @Jameson thanks, I'll check that out.

Comment: @sprinter it's a non-Java 8 implementation, we're on 1.7

Comment: Can you show us `findPreviousDecisionEventId`'s signature, or can you at least confirm it is public and non-final on a public non-final class?

Comment: The method is public non-final, on a public  non-final class. The class is an  instantiation of a static inner class, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: @JeffBowman I added the method above

Comment: There was an answer below, it suggested I try `Optional.<String>of("testid");` I tried it, but the result was the same. There are other when/then statements that use `Optional` this way, they work fine.

Comment: Sorry my answer was no good. What VM and what version of Mockito? Also, try to make an [mcve] if possible

Comment: @DavidRawson it looks like the standard jvm, and Mockito 1.9. I'll see what I can do about the example.

Comment: Two things: A) using Optional for return types is regarded as bad practice (by the inventors of it; other people are more relaxed on that) B) there is Mockito 2.7 already; coming with a ton of interesting features. Consider upgrading. No idea about your current problem though ;-)

Comment: My hunch is that you're calling the actual implementation of `findPreviousDecisionEventId`, because that's the only way you're going to get an absent `Optional`. I don't know _why_, though, since the class and method seem to be mockable. You can test by having the real `findPreviousDecisionEventId` throw an exception, and see if that happens in the test.

Comment: @GhostCat Do you mean "using Optional<> in _parameters_ is bad practice"? I presume you're referring to the OP's method `isSupportChanged`

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, I've been reading up on Optional, I'm going to refactor my code so the optional is checked before the method call. Yeah, I'll see if it's possible to upgrade Mockito.

Comment: @JeffBowman OK thanks, I'll give that a shot.